# apache not rendering special characters

Tags: php, html, apache

After migrating our system over to Amazon EC2, special characters like German letters do not render properly. I have read through a couple articles that address this by modifying the .htaccess file:    http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

Our pages are dynamically generated and they all have the meta tag -

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

None of the commands worked.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<filesMatch ".(htm|html|css|js)$">
ForceType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
</filesMatch>

<filesMatch ".(htm|html|css|js)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Are your files also encoded with UTF-8?

Comment: Presumably, your data is not encoded as UTF-8 (hence why saying it is UTF-8 isn't fixing the problem).

Comment: all the html files are

Comment: Are you sure that your FTP client or whatever tool you use to upload your files is not messing up your files encoding? And you say that your pages are dynamically generated, do you send a UTF8 http header? Are your PHP files utf-8 also?

Comment: apache doesn't "render" things. your browser does that.

Comment: Consider posting a URL. It would let us see both the HTTP headers actually sent and the content of the data.

Comment: You are correct Marc, I misspoke, here is a link http://mammacare.com/Specialist_graduates.php?a_id=497

Answer (score 0):

> http://mammacare.com/Specialist_graduates.php?a_id=497

The data on that page is "ISO Latin 1" encoded, not UTF-8. Easy to test by switching your browser to Latin-1 (*View > Encoding* or similar).

Comment: ok then how do I encode it properly if neither the meta tag nor the .htaccess directives are not working?

Comment: You need to save the **actual data** in UTF-8. The meta tags and headers just tell the browser how it should interpret the data, it doesn't change the encoding. Your problem is that the actual encoding and the encoding your meta data claims don't match.